# Why "this" works but "Form.Activeform" throws NullRefernceException?

Tags: c#

if this keyword refers to the current instance of the class as instanced in  program class(Application.Run(new Form1()))

we can reach it's properties with this keyword

```
        this .Text = "debuggging";
        this .Opacity = 54;
        this .ShowIcon = true;
        this .Size = new Size(100, 100);
```

why cant ı reach it with Form1.ActiveForm.***(All properties)

just out of curiosity  but why

when coded like this

```
        Form1.ActiveForm.Text = "debugla";
        Form1.ActiveForm.Opacity = 54;
        Form1.ActiveForm.ShowIcon = true;
        Form1.ActiveForm.Size = new Size(100, 100);
```

and activeform must bring us the currently active form used

it throws nullreference exception     why    ?

Comment: How about posting the error message you get?

Comment: [MSDN: Form.ActiveForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform(v=vs.110).aspx): _"A Form that represents the currently active form, or **null** if there is no active form."_

Comment: Writing `Form1.ActiveForm` is a bit confusing since this `static` property is actually defined on the base class, `Form`. The expression `ActiveForm == this` is only true if (1) there is a `Form` which is active right now, and (2) the form which is active right now, is an instance of `Form1`, and is the same instance of it as `this` is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MSDN: `Form.ActiveForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *"A Form that represents the currently active form, or **null** if there is no active form."*

So maybe because you are debugging the form is not active(has not focus), therefore it returns `null`.

Comment: You are whole right about it the PROBLEM is debugging BECAUSE I was debugging the application before Form is showed up  so the control isn't displayed or clicked on it  that means has't got focus that also means isN't active ,  so  Form1.Activeform is Null   but if ı don't debug and let Form open ,being showed   ,   this =(equals to)  form.Activeform  becasue  form hasgot focus after being showed   , so happy to learn diffrerence thanks

Answer (score 5):

[ActiveForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the active form... this means that if your window doesn't have focus, then it is not active. Therefore by using it in this way you greatly risk your program producing an error.

Using `this` ensures you are accessing the form you are intending to change

You should also note that `ActiveForm` is a static property and therefore it has no link whatsoever to the form you are using it in if you have any other windows open in your application then your changes could apply to these other dialogs

Comment: You are whole right about it the PROBLEM is debugging BECAUSE I was debugging the application before Form is showed up  so the control isn't displayed or clicked on it  that means has't got focus that also means isN't active ,  so  Form1.Activeform is Null   but if ı don't debug and let Form open ,being showed   ,   this =(equals to)  form.Activeform  becasue  form hasgot focus after being showed   , so happy to learn diffrerence thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 Form currentForm = Form.ActiveForm;

 if(currentForm != null)
 {
     //use currentForm properties
 }
```

`Form.ActiveForm`[`gets the currently active form for this application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

while [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) refers to current instance of `Form1`.